# how to call a function in directive after receiving data from two different services?

Tags: angularjs

I have lot of service call in my controller, after getting the data from those service, i want to trigger a function in directive.

> // This is my controller
>
> function myctrl() {
>
> ```
>     Serv.query({"type":"PageDetails"}, request.pageDetails, function(data) {
>         if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
>             $scope.display.pageDetails = data.list;
>
>             Serv.query({"type":"userDetails"}, request.userDetails, function(data) {
>                     if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
>                         $scope.display.userDetails = data.list;
>                         $scope.loaded = true;
>                     }
>             });
>         }
>     });
> ```
>
> }
>
> // This is my service factory
>
> ```
> app.factory('KYC',function($resource) {
>     return $resource('serviceUrl/:type',{}, {
>         query: {method: 'POST', isArray: false},
>         get: {method: 'GET',    isArray: false}
>     });  
> });
> ```
>
> // this is my directive
>
> ```
> app.directive('showSlowly',function() {
>     return {
>         restrict: 'EA',
>         link: function(scope, element, attrs){
>             scope.$watch('loaded', function(isLoaded) {
>                 if(isLoaded) {
>                     setTimeout(function() {
>                         $(element).animate({height:"140px"}, 'slow', function(){
>                             $(element).css({overflow:"visible"});
>                         });
>                     }, 300);
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     };
> });
> ```

This is not the best way. 
Can any one help to get this done with $q. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `This is not the best way`...not clear what you are referring to

Comment: @charlietfl calling services synchronously.

Comment: depending on how your html is configured...you may not even need to watch `loaded`. Create a demo in plunker

Comment: @charlietfl forget about my dom.  my reqmt is adding a small animation to a widget after everthing loads. i have given a sample above. And i have to try out the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i am able to achieve this with $q.all().

```
//this is my controller code

function myctrl($q, $scope) {
    var deferredObjs = {
        "d1":$q.defer,
        "d2":$q.defer
    } 
    $scope.promises = { "p1":d1.promise,"p2":d2.promise};

    Serv.query({"type":"PageDetails"}, request.pageDetails, function(data) {
        if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
            $scope.display.pageDetails = data.list;
            $scope.apply(function() {
                deferredObjs.d1.resolve();
            }
        }else {
            $scope.apply(function() {
                deferredObjs.d1.reject();
            }
        }
    });

    Serv.query({"type":"userDetails"}, request.userDetails, function(data) {
        if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
            $scope.display.userDetails = data.list;
            $scope.apply(function() {
                deferredObjs.d2.resolve();
            }
        }else {
            $scope.apply(function() {
                deferredObjs.d2.reject();
            }
        }
    });
}

// this is my directive

app.directive('showSlowly',function($q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $q.all([scope.promises.p1.then(function(){}), scope.promises.p2.then(function(){}]).then(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(element).animate({height:"140px"}, 'slow', function(){
                            $(element).css({overflow:"visible"});
                        });
                    }, 300);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it seems like you want code to execute once the data has loaded.  It seems like your code should be working as is, but if you want to try something different that uses `$q`, then you can make `$scope.loaded` a promise.  Your other code can reference that promise, and pass it methods to run when the promise is resolved (which is a lot like setting up a `$watch` to run a method when the value changes)

**Controller code:**

Very similar to what you have now... first, make sure you're injecting `$q` in your controller/app.  Then, create a promise and store it in `loaded`:

```
var loadedDefer = $q.defer();
$scope.loaded = loadedDefer.promise;
```

Then inside your query success, instead of setting `loaded = true`, use

```
loadedDefer.resolve(true);
```

(you could pass any object to the resolve method, but I chose `true` because that's what your current code is already looking for.)

**Directive code:**

Instead of using `$watch`, you can use the promise directly.

```
$scope.loaded.then( function(isLoaded){...} );
```

This setup works very similarly to what you've already done, but it's good to get familiar with $q and use it when it's appropriate.

Comment: no i want to call the services asynchronously. not one inside another

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for... could you explain what you mean?  Both your current code and my sample code are asynchronous already, and I don't know what you mean by 'one inside another'.

Comment: instead of calling one service inside another, i want to call both the services parallely. one service result is not needed in another service, i mean no dependency.